# PC or mac for multi OS?

Tags: laptop, operating-systems, bios

I have to use MacOS in my school but i am a bloody windows user and I need Linux too,
I have almost NO background in Mac.

So i was wondering Should I get PC or Mac Laptop ?

UPDATE: As I have to use Mac-OS then probably this gonna be my primary OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends a bit on what your primary system should be. It sounds like you want to keep using Windows.

---

If the available Macbooks fit your needs and budget, this is probably your best choice for hassle-free use of Mac OS X. Beware of missing keys on the keyboard when using Windows or Linux though.

With rEFIt you can boot into more than two systems, and you can always fall back on virtual machines (Linux VM on Windows or Mac OS X; Windows VM on Mac OS X) if you don't want to reboot.

---

Otherwise (regular non-Apple machine) you'd need to look into [Mac OS X hardware compatibility](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page#Hardware), and it is unsupported by Apple (and perhaps even illegal, depending on your jurisdiction).

Comment: As i Have to use to use MacOS that should be my primary OS

Comment: @Omeid In that case you should probably choose a Macbook for the fully supported system you *need* to use and fall back on Linux and Windows using virtual machines or multi-boot options like Bootcamp, and/or rEFIt. If you keep an open mind and don't have specific software needs you might be able to go full-time with Mac OS X.

Comment: thanks for answer, Just one more question I have lots of software/files that I use in windows and i need them will I be able to access a FAT32/NTFS partition on an external USB hard-disk  in mac while i have windows in multiboot or either virtual machine ?

Comment: @Omeid Sure you can, both from your multi-boot system and VM -- in those cases, you're running a full Windows system and can therefore access your files like on any Windows machine. Mac OS X also supports read/write of FAT32, read-only NTFS, but you can use MacFUSE and NTFS-3g to get write support. Just use the search function on this site for more information. With the Bootcamp drivers, your Windows system can even access your Mac OS X partition's files.

Comment: thanks for answer, But it looks like i have to stuck with Mac which i really don't like it, I was going to get rid of Microsoft by using opensource but it looks like I have to stuck with an other devil for sick of school.

Answer (score 1):

With a Mac computer you can always run bootcamp or virtualization software like Virtualbox, VMWare or Parallels to run the Windows or Linux.

On a non-mac computer you don't have a (proper) method of running OS X, which you say is a requirement for your school.

Comment: Can't I install Windows or Linux for Mac for multi-boot ? like in PC you can install Windows And Linux together ?

Comment: I think you might end up needing to use something like rEFIt http://refit.sourceforge.net/ to accomplish that

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably (or legally, depending on your jurisdiction) run Mac OS X on a PC, so you don't really have a choice there: get a Mac. You can run both Windows and Linux on a Mac.